# server for replacing text

Tags: text

I have a large key-value database of words. Each entry is a word that replaces another word. I am given a continuous stream of text where I have to replace the words with corresponding words in the database.

For example when I want to cache web pages I use a caching reverse proxy such as varnish. When I want text indexing, I use an indexing service such as apache solr. They can be used as dedicated services that are good at what they do.

Are there any server softwares that can do such text processing/replacement efficiently?

Comment: What's your definition of "large"?

Comment: @jamieb millions of words

Comment: How large is the database?

Comment: @mdpc it is 80-100 megabytes

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Comment: The FAQ is not clear to me. It does not clarify how this question doesn't fit the Q&A format. Neither does the barbie picture.